Cross-Field validation issue

2024/08 - EDIT: There was indeed a typo in the form, the form was
re-initiated elsewhere in the code

I have something weird;
I have a reactive form that get's initialized at the ngOnInit phase of the page-load. It attached a cross-field validator upon form initiation, like so:
this.form = this.fb.group(new CheckinForm(), 
   { validators: MultiControlValidator(['email','phoneNumber'], null)});

When doing this in a 'normal page' the validator fires once but then doesn't stay active on the form and hence doesn't validate.
If I initiate the exact same form in a Modal then the validator works without issue and invalidates the form if both email and phoneNumber are empty.
It is just when attaching it to the form in a non-modal page that it doesn't seem to fire?
Anybody know if there is a a difference between a FormGroup in a modal window vs just a normal form page?
for completeness sake below the code for the MultiControlValidator which allows multiple controls to the 'optional required field' (i.e. one of the selected fields needs to have a value for the validator to return null)
export function MultiControlValidator(controls: string[], value: any = null): ValidatorFn {
  return (form: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const values = controls.map(key => form.get(key)?.value);
    const touched = controls.map(key => form.get(key)?.touched);
    const error: ValidationErrors = { 'multiControl': true };

    if (touched.some(e => e==true) && values.every(e => e==value))
      controls.forEach(key => {
        const ctrl = form.get(key);
        ctrl?.markAsTouched();
        ctrl?.setErrors(error);
      });
    else
    {
      controls.forEach(key => {
        const ctrl = form.get(key);
        let errors = ctrl?.errors;
        if(errors?.hasOwnProperty('multiControl')) delete errors['multiControl'];
        if (errors !== undefined)
        {
          errors = ({}) ? null : errors;
          ctrl?.setErrors(errors);
        }
      });
    }
    return (touched.some(e => e==true) && values.every(e => e==value)) ? error : null;
  }
}


It shouldn't make a difference if the form is in the modal or on the page. There is likely a mistake in your code. Please try to setup a minimal reproduction in StackBlitz.
